# user-select on a tel type input

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to click into an input box, that happens to have a type of "tel", and automatically select the numerical values already in the input box. I have been trying to use the 'user-select: all' function, but I cannot get it to work. Here is an example of the situation:

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 100px;
}

input+span {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

input:invalid+span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "✖";
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #8b0000;
}

input:valid+span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "✓";
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #009000;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="telNo">Enter a telephone number (required): </label>
    <input id="telNo" name="telNo" type="tel" required value="123456" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ideally, I would like to find a way to do this without altering the html, as I don't have direct access to the html, but have full access to the css and js.

Many thanks!

I tried applying the user-select function in many different ways with no success, like below:

```
input[type="tel"] {
      -webkit-user-select: all;
      -ms-user-select: all;
      user-select: all;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have access to `JavaScript`, here's a quick possible solution that selects the text as soon as the user focuses the `input` (like when clicking inside or `tab`bing to the `input` element):

```js
const telInp = document.getElementById('telNo');

telInp.addEventListener('focus', () => telInp.select());
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 100px;
}

input+span {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

input:invalid+span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "✖";
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #8b0000;
}

input:valid+span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "✓";
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #009000;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="telNo">Enter a telephone number (required): </label>
    <input id="telNo" name="telNo" type="tel" required value="123456" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also, the `user-select` `CSS` property *"controls whether the user can select text"* <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)</sup> and it **DOES NOT** select the text in an input (or any other element).

> Learn more about [`HTMLInputElement.select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) method.

---

### UPDATE

So, as asked by the OP (in the comments), I will provide a way to enable text auto selection on multiple `input`s in the page. To do so here's a little explanation of *a possible way* to get things done:

- Give the `input`s a `class` (a `CSS` class)
- Grab (or select) those `input`s in the `JavaScript` part based on the `class` already applied to them.
- finally, loop through the `input`s and apply our `focus` event listener to each one so it automatically selects its text when focused.

Here's a live demo:

```js
/** select all the inputs based on the "selectable" class */
const telInps = document.querySelectorAll('.selectable');

/** loop through them and apply our focus event handler */
telInps.forEach(inp => inp.addEventListener('focus', () => inp.select()));
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 100px;
}

input+span {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

input:invalid+span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "✖";
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #8b0000;
}

input:valid+span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "✓";
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #009000;
}
```

```html
<!-- we gave the "selectable" class to the inputs so we can easily select them in the JS part -->
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="telNo1">Enter a telephone number (required): </label>
    <input class="selectable" id="telNo1" name="telNo1" type="tel" required value="123456" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="telNo2">Enter a telephone number (required): </label>
    <input class="selectable" id="telNo2" name="telNo2" type="tel" required value="00000" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="telNo3">Enter a telephone number (required): </label>
    <input class="selectable" id="telNo3" name="telNo3" type="tel" required value="11111" />
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

> Just to clarify, the above solution **is not** the only possible way to get things done. You may have other solutions, like using another selector, something like `input[type="tel"]` which allows you to ditch applying a new class to each `input`.

> Learn more about [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.

Comment: Would you know how to apply this same function to multiple 'tel' type questions without having to duplicate the JavaScript for each id?

Comment: yes we could do that. I'll update my answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @MikeyPeebs I have updated my answer, you may take a look.

Comment: I used your 'input[type="tel"]' suggestion and now it works throughout my whole survey. Absolutely perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MikeyPeebs Great to here that! Glad I managed to help you. If you've found my answer helpful, kindly set it as the *accepted answer*.